# Bronze Service Package for UK visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, premium-services

I have applied for UK visitor visa from USA. I was forced to buy bronze service package in order to proceed for biometrics appointment. There is no clear instructions as to once the appointment is taken, how having bronze service package will help for the next steps. Does it making the visa processing time better ? Do they help with the list of documents to be submitted ? Can I have a refund on the service package ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If this is via Qatar, here's what [VFS says](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/qat/en/ita/additional-services):

> Bronze Premium Package
>
> Description:
>
> This is VFS Global’s most frequently asked-for services, all in one
> great-value package.
>
> You can pay for this Service either online or at the visa center using
> credit or debit Visa or MasterCard. If you choose to pay online, you
> must bring the printed payment receipt to the center to obtain the
> service.
>
> Including our most popular services
>
> Document Scanning Assistance - Speedy scanning preparation to save you
> time
>
> SMS Service - Get instant visa application updates sent to your phone

Comment: Thanks! I applied for UK visa from USA. And they didn't allow me to proceed further till I take one of the service. So I had to pay:( Thanks for replying though.

Comment: Decisions on UK visas are taking much longer than normal. The website says average 6 weeks, a friend of mine applied 8 weeks ago and is still waiting for the decision.

Comment: Did you friend apply from USA ? Also, did he/she take any of the service package ?

Comment: No to both questions, however it’s now 9 weeks and still nothing. An email asking for a progress update at 6 weeks just resulted in a standard ‘still being processed’ reply. And I just noticed the official website now says average wait is 7 weeks. According to https://www.bindmans.com/insight/updates priority processing services on all visa applications were suspended earlier in 2022